# How to add a button to delete data without using params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting back into programming but I'm having trouble with this basic thing.  So I've scraped products from a web site then inserted them into a DB.  Then I list those products on my web site.  Now I'm trying to add a delete button next to each of those product that are listed on my web site.  I've tried using the solutions found on stackoverflow but I can't seem to get any of them to work.  I know this is a basic question, but I appreciate the help.

Controller

```
class IbottaController < ApplicationController

def save
    require 'watir'
    require 'phantomjs'

    @browser = Watir::Browser.new:phantomjs
    @browser.goto "https://ibotta.com/rebates"
    @button = @browser.button(class: "see-more-label")

    Ibotta.delete_all
    # if x = 24 then I get 492 products 
    # if x = 23 then I get 472 products
    x = 24
    y = 0
    while y < x 
    @button.click
    y+=1
    end

    @products = @browser.divs(class: "offer-card")

    @products.each do |a|
        # if Ibotta.find_by title: a.imgs[0].alt

        if a.divs[2].text.split("").include?('%')

        else
            value_placeholder = a.divs[3].text.split(" ")
            value_placeholder.delete("cash")
            value_placeholder.delete("back")
            value_placeholder = value_placeholder.join(" ").split("")
            value_placeholder.delete("$")
            value_placeholder = value_placeholder.join("")

            Ibotta.create(title: a.imgs[0].alt, values: value_placeholder, store: a.divs[5].text, link: a.links[0].href)
        end
    end
    @products = Ibotta.all
end


def show
    @products = Ibotta.all
end


def delete
    Ibotta.delete_all
    @products = Ibotta.all
end


def practice

end

end
```

View

```
<h1>Show Page for iBotta</h1>

<h3><%= @products.length %> products in the iBotta DB</h3>

<% @products.each do |x| %>
    <p>Title: <a href=<%=x.link%>><%= x.title %></a> </p> 
    <p>Value: <%= x.values %> </p>
    <p>Store: <%= x.store %> </p>
<% end %>
```

If you also have advice on what code I need to add, could you mention what file to add the code in?  Thanks.

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles

  get 'scraper/ibotta'
  get 'scraper/checkout51'
  get 'ibotta/save'
  get 'ibotta/show'
  get 'ibotta/delete'
  get 'targetcoupon/save'
  get 'targetcoupon/delete'
  get 'targetcoupon/show'
  get 'targetibottum/delete'
  get 'targetibottum/show'
  get 'targetibottum/save'
  get 'savingstar/delete'
  get 'savingstar/save'
  get 'savingstar/show'
  get 'ibottasavingstar/show'
  get 'ibottasavingstar/save'
  get 'ibottasavingstar/delete'
  get 'targetcoupon/practice'
  get 'targetibottasavingstar/show'
  get 'targetibottasavingstar/save'
  get 'targetibottasavingstar/delete'
  get 'checkout51/save'  
  get 'checkout51/show' 
  get 'checkout51/delete'
  get 'checkout51/practice'

  get 'ibotta/practice'

  get 'ibottacheckout51/save'  
  get 'ibottacheckout51/show' 
  get 'ibottacheckout51/delete'

  get 'ibottacheckout51/practice'  

  get 'newcheckout51/save'  
  get 'newcheckout51/show' 
  get 'newcheckout51/delete'

  get 'smiths/save'
  get 'smiths/show'
  get 'smiths/delete'
  get 'smiths/practice'
```

Comment: Show output of `rails routes` (or `rake routes` in older Rails versions). Deletion code looks fine (tho `delete_all` won't trigger any callbacks), so all You got to do is route it correctly. But are You sure You need to assign @products in delete action? Looks like You are using `get` request to delete, but It should be `delete` one, and in delete action after `Ibotta.delete_all` You probably should redirect to other path instead of assigning products and rendering delete view

Comment: I want to add a button to delete products individually, not all at once.

Comment: As @JakubKopyś suggested, can you show the rake routes output?
generally for deleting some entry you would have to send params,so that rails can select & delete that particular entry (product)
for eg.for deleting a particular comment (same as deleting a particular product):-
<%= link_to 'delete',"/comments/#{comment.id}",method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

PS:You can get the link_to path from rake routes

Answer (score 2):

Why don't You want to use params? I do not know If It is even possible...

With ID You could simply add something like `<%= link_to 'delete', ibotta_path(x.id), method: :delete %>` In Your view.
If You have resources routes the path helper should be avaliable for You.
Then in controller add:

```
    def destroy
      Ibotta.find(params[:id]).destroy
      redirect_to your_redirect_path
    end
```

EDIT: I see that You are not using resources routing - add `delete 'ibotta/:id', to: 'ibotta#destroy'` to Your `routes.rb` or just use [resources routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

So Your view would look like:

```
<% @products.each do |x| %>
    <p>Title: <a href=<%=x.link%>><%= x.title %></a> </p> 
    <p>Value: <%= x.values %> </p>
    <p>Store: <%= x.store %> </p>
    <p><%= link_to 'delete', ibotta_path(x.id), method: :delete %></p>
<% end %>
```

One note - I think You shouldn't use variable names like 'x' in each block, use 'product' instead, it is much more descriptive.

Comment: So I added the new code that goes in the view and for the routes I added resources :ibotta    And when I click on the delete button it redirects me to a new page but it doesn't delete the product.  Thoughts?

Comment: hmmmm... maybe `Ibotta.find(params[:id]).destroy!` - should throw exception if it fails, then You can check out server logs to see what failed. Feel free to share error message (if any),

Comment: Added it, but am getting nothing in the console.  This was a big help though and a good start, thank you.